# Function of defining an absolute URL in a model in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I am currently completing the final capstone project for Django on Codecademy, and I've come across a comprehension issue.

On Codecademy, they state that [it's used to redirect to the homepage when a user submits data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DgOG4.png), while the [Django documentation for get_absolute_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/instances/#get-absolute-url) seems to make no reference to redirects.

I currently have no absolute urls defined for any of my models, and these are my [url patterns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nuOuO.png) and [views](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xwSEC.png).

At this stage, I'm just trying to understand the purpose of defining an absolute URL in a model, and where the appropriate places to utilize it are. I'm very confused about it's function currently, and would appreciate a simplified explanation with examples.

Comment: The generic editing views use it as the default redirect URL if it's defined https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/#model-forms - `You don’t even need to provide a success_url for CreateView or UpdateView - they will use get_absolute_url() on the model object if available.`

Comment: So for example, when submitting a new Ingredient with a form in the example I provided, if an absolute URL has been defined as the homepage, once the form is submitted, the user would automatically be returned there?